# WpAllImport - Map Value based on node title

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, wpallimport

In the xml I am importing I am trying to map a value based on a XML Element title.

For example this is a part of the xml:

```
<studentHome>no</studentHome>
<familyHome>no</familyHome>
<luxHome>no</luxHome>
```

I am trying to check if the value is 'yes' then return the title of the element. So if  value is yes then the import process must return studentHome.

I tried by using the `wp_all_import_is_post_to_update` filter by using the `$xml_node` with no luck. Is there another way?

Comment: I'd just use a tiny custom PHP function, that you can input directly in the import configuration. https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/inline-php/

Comment: But how I can check the title of the element?

Comment: There is no title, you mean the tag/element _name_. I don't know if you explicitly have access to those during the import, if you don't hook into anything - but you can simply hard-code it, no? Make your custom function take a parameter, and then supply `'studentHome'` as a string value in the call for that specific field.

Comment: Yes thats the only way probably... it has to be hardcoded if I cant access the element name...

Comment: "Hardcoded" in your import configuration only though ... You need to drag the `{foobar[1]}` column reference into the input field for the field that you are importing into anyway, so adding a static text literal in that same place manually, should be a minor inconvenience at most?